# django - render to response from function - not working

Tags: python, django

I have a view like this :

```
  def myview(request):
      print "A"

      some_function()

      return HttpResponse("This should not appear")

  def some_function():
      return render_to_response("templ.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here,  the function renders template if i call the function like this :

```
    return some_function()
```

But it always expect the function to return, but i want the function to return only at certain times. I can use some logic in the view whether to return or not, but i am asking it is possible to do everything in the view so i can simply call the function ?

Comment: I was misled by question at first, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The question is rather confusing. Please clarify what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a response from a function, but what you need is `return some_function()` not `some_function()` alone,
in your case some_function() does execute, but the return value is not passed on as the return value of your view `myview()`

So the execution flow continues and reaches `return HttpResponse("This should not appear")`,
so that is the response you will get in your view.

If you had `some_function()` alone (and without `return`), then your view would return with no response (`myview()` being a function that returns nothing),
and Django would complain.

You can use logic to control the flow ofcourse, provided you use `return` on the called functions, e.g. :

```
def my_view(request):

    if request['x'] == 'a':
        return function_a()
    elif request['x'] == 'b':
        return function_b()

    return some_other_response()
```

Just make `function_x()` return a valid response.